# Why all my scripts are being loaded together and they return not found after a few days?

Tags: php

I have php scripts in my website and at the top of the page css and js are being loaded like below

```
<link href="css/pageLayout.css?version=4" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,print">
<link href="css/style.css?version=4" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,print">
<script src="validation.js?version=4" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="numcheck.js?version=4" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when I view source of my page the links are like below

```
<link href="css/pageLayout.css,qv==4+style.css,qv==4.pagespeed.cc.E_3tcdStoh.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,print">
<script src="Script/validation.js,qv==4+numcheck.js,qv==4.pagespeed.jc.-0oIAICDu_.js"></script>
```

It seems someone/something is putting all my files together, must be some component in either the server or the browser, but I can't seem to find it.

At first, it works without any problem, so I didn't notice. But after a few days these put together files are not found anymore and returns 401 not found, and none of the css and js works anymore.
It works again if I change the link of the file by changing the version number `version`, but returns after a few days. Any idea what might be the reason?

Comment: You probably have the [pagespeed module](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/) installed on your server, Adding `ModPagespeed off` to the `.htaccess` file will stop it

Comment: apparently, pagespeed module was configured in whm, which I could not find earlier. Turning it off really solved the problem. I am wondering why pagespeed would not work thought, might be a bug...